# Proof of Theorem 4.2 in Elements of Causal Inference

Tags: causality

I'm a novice in the field of causal inference, and was going through material on Structure Identifiability in the textbook 'Elements of Causal Inference'. I am unable to get an intuition about the following theorem:

**Theorem 4.2** (Identifiability of linear non-Gaussian models): Assume that $P_{X, Y}$ admits the linear model
$$
Y=\alpha X+N_Y, \quad N_Y \perp\kern-5pt\perp X,
$$
with continuous random variables $X, N_Y$, and $Y$. Then there exist $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ random variable $N_X$ such that
$$
X=\beta Y+N_X, \quad N_X \perp\kern-5pt\perp Y,
$$
if and only if $N_Y$ and $X$ are Gaussian.

Here's the proof of this theorem, as also given in the textbook:

Proof of Theorem $4.2$

We first state a lemma.

**Lemma C.1** Let $X$ and $N$ be independent wariables and assume that $N$ is nondeterministic. Then $N \not(X+N)$.
Proof of Theorem 4.2. If $X$ and $N_Y$ are normally distributed, we have
$$
\beta:=\frac{\operatorname{cov}[X, Y]}{\operatorname{cov}[Y, Y]}=\frac{\alpha \operatorname{var}[X]}{\alpha^2 \operatorname{var}[X]+\operatorname{var}\left[N_Y\right]}
$$
and define $N_X:=X-\beta Y . N_X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated by construction and because $N_X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian, it follows that they are independent, too.
To prove the "only if" statement, we assume that
$Y=\alpha X+N_Y$ and $N_X=(1-\alpha \beta) X-\beta N_Y$
are independent. Distinguish between the following cases

(i) $(1-\alpha \beta) \neq 0$ and $\beta \neq 0$.
Here, Theorem $4.3$ implies that $X, N_Y$ and thus also $Y, N_X$ are normally distributed. Hence, $P_{X, Y}$ is bivariate Gaussian, too.
(ii) $\beta=0$.
This implies
$$
X \perp\kern-5pt\perp \alpha X+N_Y,
$$
which is a contradiction to Lemma C.1.

(iii) $(1-\alpha \beta)=0$.
It follows $-\beta N_Y \perp \alpha X+N_Y$. Thus
$$
N_Y \perp\kern-5pt\perp \alpha X+N_Y,
$$
which, again, contradicts Lemma C.1.
This concludes the proof.

where, Theorem 4.3 (Darmois-Skitovič):
Let $X_1, \ldots, X_d$ be independent, non-degenerate random variables. If there exist non-vanishing coefficients $a_1, \ldots, a_d$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_d$ (that is, for all $i, a_i \neq 0 \neq b_i$ ) such that the two linear combinations
$$
\begin{array}{l}
l_1=a_1 X_1+\ldots+a_d X_d, \\
l_2=b_1 X_1+\ldots+b_d X_d
\end{array}
$$
are independent, then each $X_i$ is normally distributed.

---

My question: where do the three conditions for independence of $Y and N_x$ come from?
Can anyone shed more light on the intuition that guides this proof? I'm getting so lost in the maths part of it, that I keep missing the point. Thanks!

Comment: The three conditions describe a partition of the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Condition 1 describes the case if $\alpha\beta\neq 1$, which would cover most configurations. The remaining conditions are only to show that any other configuration of $\alpha\beta$ would result in a contradiction.